# how can css reset :hover to default state?

Tags: css, hover, default

I have the following rule:

```
.quiz .panel .choices a:hover,
.quiz .panel .choices a:active {background-position: 0 -30px;}
```

And because of the well documented weirdness that iOS does when it interacts with `:hover`. I want to reset the `<a>` tag to its normal CSS state for iOS. In my page, javascript will inject a class called 'iOS' at a top level so my following rule that will overwrite would be:

```
.iOS .quiz .panel .choices a:(?????)
```

the question marks being the part I don't know. What CSS rule do I write that resets the `<a>` tag so the pseudo classes are at their default state?

Comment: I haven't experimented any of this with iOS, but what happens when you have `.iOS .quiz .panel .choices a { background-position: 0 0;}`? Does that not reset it?

Comment: yes, I've been running tests and you are correct Andrew. I awarded the correct answer to Ivozor as he posted the same thing as you but a few minutes before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No pseudo-class at all. Just use:

```
.iOS .quiz .panel .choices a
```

It will be the selected rule when "hover" doesn't happen! :)

Comment: so 
    .iOS .quiz .panel .choices a
will remove the pseudo class?

Comment: I've been running tests and this is the correct answer.  By rewriting the rule for just the a tag, all pseudo classes are removed. Then new ones can be written

Answer (score 2):

I didnt really understand your question, but the 4 options you have are

```
a:link
a:hover
a:active
a:visited
```

my guess is you need

```
.iOS .quiz .panel .choices a:link {background-position: 0 0}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
body:not(.iOS) .quiz .panel .choices a:hover,
.quiz .panel .choices a:active {background-position: 0 -30px;}
```

Repeat the `not` for the `:active` line if necessary. Also swap `body` with a selector that matches whichever element you apply the `.iOS` class to.

Comment: (This replaces your existing line, it's not added on to the end.)

Comment: Its a nice idea but :not is css3 and I need :hover to work for legacy browsers.  You are on the right track though in that i want:hover for the exclusion of iOS.  But I want to do it with an overwrite. In other words a rule that removes :hover pseudoclass from the <a > tag

Comment: `:not()` is supported for most legacy browsers except IE<=8. If you need to support those as well, I'd suggest just adding it in a conditional comment.

Comment: See compatibility tables at the bottom of https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/:not